# How to edit nested models with ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm looking to do something similar to [Railscasts Episode#196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [Railscasts Episode#197](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) in ASP.NET MVC3.

I have two models and `Order` and `LineItem`, and `Order` contains at least one `LineItem`.  When the user is creating the order I will set the form up with one entry editor for the `LineItem` (I've already created a EditorTemplate for this and that's working fine.  I would like to use jQuery to dynamically add more editors for the `LineItem`.

```
public class Order : EntityObject {
    public string CustomerName { get;set; }
    public EntityCollection<LineItem> LineItems { get;set; }
}

public class LineItem : EntityObject {
    public long ProductId { get;set; }
    public string Description { get;set; }
    public double Quantity { get;set; }
}
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Something to keep in mind when working with Lists/Dictionaries in MVC is that model binding will throw away all data that follows the first disjoint indexes unless you use custom indexers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-MVC3 posts, but it still applies:

[Using ASP.NET MVC Partial Views for Dynamic JavaScript Rendering](http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/using-aspnet-mvc-partial-views-for-dynamic-javascript-rendering/)

[Render Your Model With Client Side jQuery Templates Instead of ASP.NET MVC Partial Views](http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/render-your-model-with-client-side-jquery-templates-instead-of-asp-net-mvc-partial-views/)

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for.  I'm hoping to do something similar to this, however, [this approach](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) doesn't quite work for nested models.